# Cant modify objects from Mongoose document search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am trying to have a generic REST that returns all records for a given schema.

```
  /* Read all entries for a given document type, TODO: limit this to a sensible amount of records, say 500 */  
  app.get( '/data/all/:id' , verifySession , function( req, res )
  {
    exposed[req.params.id].find( {} , function(err,docs)
    { 
      if( docs && req.params.id == "Account" )
        docs.forEach( function(o){ console.log(o); delete o.salt; delete o.hash; console.log(o); } );
        res.json( err || docs ); 
    });     
  });
```

And for Accounts, I dont want to return the `hash` and `salt`, but o behaves as if it is read only. The second console.log(o) still has `salt` and `hash`.

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongoose returns Document instances, which aren't plain objects.

So you need to convert them first using [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject):

```
var documents = docs.map( function(doc) {
  doc = doc.toObject();
  delete o.salt;
  delete o.hash;
  return doc;
});
```

Alternatively, you can tell `find` to exclude `hash` and `salt` fields in the results:

```
exposed[req.params.id].find({}, '-hash -salt', function(err, docs) { ... });
```